# Execute other commands while one is already running

Tags: python

As the title states, how would I execute other commands while one is being processed already? 
Lets say hypothetically I have this:

```
import urllib.request
import re
class runCommands:
      def say(self,word):
          return word
      def rsay(self,word):
          return word[::-1]
      def urban(self,term):
          data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%s" % term).read().decode()
          definition = re.search('<div class="definition">(.*?)</div>',data).group(1)
          return definition
      def run(self):
          while True:
                command = input("Command: ")
                command,data = command.split(" ",1)
                if command == "say": print(self.say(data))
                if command == "reversesay": print(self.rsay(data))
                if command == "urbandictionary": print(self.urban(data))
```

Now, I realize that doing runCommands().run() I have to input commands one at a time but hypothetically if I could some how input multiple commands like this:

```
 me: "urbandictionary hello"
 me: "reverse hello" # before it posts the result
```

How would I get it to run both simultaneously even though it would actually do "urbandictionary hello" then "reverse hello" second I heard thready could do this but I'm not sure how would I would do that with threading. Is threading the only option to have it actually post "olleh" before it returns the urban dictionary result for hello even though I did "urbandictionary hello" first?

Comment: You need [thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html)s!

Comment: `threading`.  Also are you coming from a java background?  You don't need a class to do everything, certainly not the above.

Comment: you don't need threads.  you could use Twisted, grequests, or even subprocesses.  it looks like you're on python 3, so you could also give asyncio a whirl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a job `Queue` and `threading` module.

Here is an example to inspire you and get you started:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```